# LCD outputs japanese characters I have tried everything

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, lcd

I am at last resort, I have tried everything!

I changed libraries
I changed pins multiple times
I tried to mix up pins
I went on all possibles sites including ada, sparkfun anything
I tried custom characters and make my own characters

This thing just does not want to work...
My problem is that the lcd is showing Japanese characters instead of alphanumeric.

I am working with arduino uno and the hitachi

Here is my code, below the different set ups I have tried.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>



//LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,2,7,8,10,9);




void setup(){

  lcd.begin(20, 4);

}

void loop(){

  lcd.print("LCD!");
  delay(6000);

  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print("Hello everyone! JAPAN!");
  delay(3000);

  lcd.clear();

  lcd.blink();
  delay(4000);
  lcd.setCursor(7,1);
  delay(3000);
  lcd.noBlink();

  lcd.cursor();
  delay(4000);
  lcd.noCursor();

  lcd.clear();


}
```

Here are the setups tried:

[1](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/002/364/original/learn_arduino_fritzing.jpg?1396782290)

[2](http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-a-character-LCD-with-an-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS)

[3](https://youtu.be/drqHD0sEc5k?t=1m6s)

Do you think it's just the display and should give up?

Thanks

Comment: This does not belong here, but on arduino.stackexchange.com. Post it there, especially if desperate - low probability for someone here to guide you with diagnostics (it's a hardware problem likely).

Answer (score 0):

One thing I might try for the sake of diagnosing the issue is removing the HDMI cable from the Arduino and powering it via a 9-12v power adapter. I've had this happen to me a few times in the past when leaving the Arduino connected to my laptop, but it went away after removing the connection.

Keep in mind that display modules using the same driver won't necessarily all have the same pin-out so it's important to try to find the datasheet for the exact model that you purchased if the pins aren't labeled on the module.